# iOS-Parse How to retrieve an object given a username?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have two ViewControllers, in the first one, there are 3 key-value pairs in each PFObject, save them to parse after clicking a button. In the second ViewController, I want to create another property and save it to the same PFObject. Here is my code:

in the first ViewController:

```
- (void)next
{
    PFObject *thisuser = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"User"];
    thisuser[@"name"] = [PFUser currentUser].username;
    thisuser[@"institution"] = institution.text;
    thisuser[@"major"] = major.text;
    [thisuser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
    {
        if (succeeded)
        {
            GuideViewController2 *GVC2 = [[GuideViewController2  alloc]initWithNibName:@"GuideViewController2" bundle:nil];
            UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:GVC2];
            nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
            nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];

            NSLog(@"success");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"nope");
        }
    }];
}
```

and in my second view controller, the user can upload a profile photo, i want this photo to be saved in the same PFObject. So is there a way to retrieve an object using `[PFUser currentUser].username` property? How do i get this user object under the User class in order to add a photo key-value pair?

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just query for the user:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:USERNAME_KEY equalTo:username];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)
{ 
    if (!error) {
       //You found the user!
       PFUser *queriedUser = (PFUser *)object;
    }

}];
```

Supposing the username is actually unique! `USERNAME_KEY` would be your username field and `username` the actual username.

Comment: actually i managed to do this by [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User" ].But thank your for the tip.

Comment: Are you using a custom user class? When querying for users, you should also user the `[PFUser query]`.